# Gulp is running task multiple times

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp task that runs multiple times every time I make a change to a file.

```js
var themename = '{MY-THENE-NAME}';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
 // Prepare and optimize code etc
 autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    flexboxfixer = require('postcss-flexboxfixer'),
 browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
 image = require('gulp-image'),
 jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
 postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
 sass = require('gulp-sass'),
 sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),

 // Only work with new or updated files
 newer = require('gulp-newer'),

 // Name of working theme folder
 root = '../' + themename + '/',
 scss = root + 'sass/',
 js = root + 'js/',
 img = root + 'images/',
 languages = root + 'languages/';

// CSS via Sass and Autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function() {
 return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
 .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
 .pipe(sass({
  outputStyle: 'expanded',
  indentType: 'tab',
  indentWidth: '1'
 }).on('error', sass.logError))
 .pipe(postcss([
  flexboxfixer,
  autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
 ]))
 .pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(root));
});

// Optimize images through gulp-image
gulp.task('images', function() {
 return gulp.src(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}')
 .pipe(newer(img))
 .pipe(image())
 .pipe(gulp.dest(img));
});

// JavaScript
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
 return gulp.src([js + '*.js'])
 .pipe(jshint())
 .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest(js));
});


// Watch everything
gulp.task('watch', function() {
 browserSync.init({
  open: 'external',
  proxy: 'localhost/{MY-THENE-NAME}',
  port: 8080
 });
 gulp.watch([root + '**/*.css', root + '**/*.scss' ], ['css']);
 gulp.watch(js + '**/*.js', ['javascript']);
 gulp.watch(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}', ['images']);
 gulp.watch(root + '**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


// Default task (runs at initiation: gulp --verbose)
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

When I run gulp (default) it runs many times. Up to 10 or even more.
It is really annoying and I have no idea how to fix it.

Can anyone help me out with why this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log` to see where things start repeating?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure how to do it properly. But terminal shows something like that  '[15:27:55] Starting 'css'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[15:27:56] Finished 'css' after 1.09 s
[15:27:56] Starting 'css'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[15:27:57] Finished 'css' after 1.38 s
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[15:27:57] Starting 'css'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[15:27:58] Finished 'css' after 708 ms

[15:28:01] Starting 'css'...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[15:28:01] Finished 'css' after 627 ms'

Comment: Could it be you're watching folders/files which are changed by the tasks? This may cause a loop

Comment: Honestly I don't think so. But I'll try to google more) Thanks for trying to help)

Comment: Can you remove the root + '**/*.css', part of your watch task and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: Mark, thanks! I removed root + '**/*.css' and now CSS task runs for one time 08:40:34] Finished 'css' after 763 ms
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
But why 'Reloading Browsers...' goes four times?